# Gecko driver not executing test cases completely

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

Below is the dependencies version i am using :

WebDriverManager-versioned **3.6.1**

(Gecko driver versioned **0.24.0**)

Firefox versioned **68.0.1 64 bit Windows 10**

Selenium version **3.141.59**

I have a maven -selenium project with 10+ test classes in testNG.

When i execute these classes on Chrome browsers ,each test class gets executed successfully .

Same test classes when i execute on Firefox using the (WebDriverManager-Gecko driver) the test classes execute for some time say 5-10 seconds and then abruptly closes and opens next test class for execution ,even this test class execute for some time and then closes . 
Same thing happens with each test class.

I have tried to manually use geckodriver.exe and set up system properties, still it doesnt fix the error

Below is the code i have used for WebDriverManager

```
if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }

            if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
```

[This is the link for the stack trace](https://pastebin.com/gbGJXzCf)

Comment: From stack trace it's error while taking screen shot it seems . Check this https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/614 .may be related

Answer (score 0):

There must be version discrepancy, just make sure your firefox version is compatible with the gecko driver and then try again.

Comment: Checked it out , Mentioned versions of browser and driver are compatible

Comment: Are you able to execute the test on chrome?

Comment: Yes it executes on chrome successfully.

Comment: Then it's sure there is a problem with the browser and gecko driver incompatibility. Downgrade your firefox browser version and try executing the tests

Comment: Can you suggest which browser and driver version should i use?

Comment: You can use version 65 for firefox with current gecko driver version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuing the versions are compatible, Check with the below code while calling the driver.

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath+"geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: I've tried this too ! still test cases are getting closed abruptly . Dont know how they are working perfectly well in chrome :(